# How to remove a div if it contains a certain string in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

there's a list of items on a page, some blank, with one example being:

```
<div class="item itemask">
  <div class="tophead">
    <div class="itemnumber">30</div>

    <a class="article" href=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomhead"> points by <a class="userlink" rel=""></a> ago&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/item?id=">discuss</a>
</div>
```

Hence, what jQuery or JavaScript could be used to find an instance of: `<a class="article" href="">` in any instance of a `div class=item` on the page, and then delete or hide that individual parent `div` of `class=item` which contains that piece of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer:** Based on clarification in comment, try this instead:

```
$('div.item:has(a.article[href=""])').remove();​
```

Or this should also work:

```
$('div.item:has(a.article:not([href]))').remove();​
```

Or if you have issues with either of those, try this:

```
$('div.item a.article').filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == '';
}).closest('div.item').remove();​​​​​​​
```

---

**Original answer:**

Using jQuery:

```
$('div.item:has(a.article)').remove();
```

This will select `<div>` elements with the class `item` that has a descendent `<a>` element with the class `article`, and remove them.

Of course, you could use `.hide()` instead if you like:

```
$('div.item:has(a.article)').hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/remove/
- http://api.jquery.com/hide/

---

If you really meant that you only want to remove the actual `parent` of the `a.article`, then you would do this:

```
$('div.item :has( > a.article)').remove();
```

This will remove the parent of `a.article` instead of the one with the `.item` class. Wasn't sure which you meant.

Comment: the first option hides all items, the second options hides the bottom part of all items. see the page here, and note the two empty items at bottom: http://bit.ly/cor8dY - that's what I'm trying to hide. The problem is that it's only class items that should be hidden that have <a> inside whose anchor is blank.

Comment: I meant specifically <a class="article"> whose href is blank - the parent div of item should be removed. - perhaps the grandparent actually. thanks.

Comment: @Adrian33 - You mean to remove the `div` *with* the class `item`, right? Your comment above makes it sound like you want the parent of that `div.item`, but that would be the `body` tag. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: @patrick - the clarification is hiding everything. http://bit.ly/di7TU5. perhaps code resembling something like:
var q = $(this).closest('.item'), any = q.find('.text:hidden').length > 0;
q.find('.text').toggle(any).prev().toggleClass('highlightc', any);

Comment: All divs with class item that contain an <a class="article"> whose href is blank should be taken out.

Comment: @Adrian33 - I placed the update at the top of the answer. Sorry for the confusion. Copy and paste that one, and let me know. - Currently you have: `$('div.item:has(a.article)').remove();` and it should be: `$('div.item:has(a.article[href=""])').remove();​`

Comment: @Adrian33 - I added 2 more solutions to the top. Not sure why the first wasn't working for you. It did for me. Anyway, if the second doesn't work, the third definitely should.

Comment: @patrick None of those worked.If you want to try locally, dl http://bit.ly/9mcSnw and insert where it says  // stack overflow insert your code here.
Thank you.

Comment: Both of you are correct. I had an issue with either my ISP or browser, when I switched to Firefox it started working. Now it's working in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

To hide:

```
$("div.item a.article[href='']").parents(".item").css('display','none');
```

To delete:

```
$("div.item a.article[href='']").parents(".item").remove();
```

Comment: this has no affect on the page

Comment: @Adrian33 - It does. It hides/deletes the `tophead` div.

Comment: @Adrian33 - I see what you want from your link. I modified the code. Try again.

Comment: @Adam - You could get away with `parents(".item")` instead of `parent().parent()`.

Comment: Thanks, but none of the above affect the page :( I can link to it.

Comment: @Adrian33 - I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. Both of Adam's example works for me: **Hide:** http://jsfiddle.net/9F7gf/ **Remove:** http://jsfiddle.net/rPGbg/

Comment: It may be due to the page it's on -- many items. I don't know. Maybe try a few code snippets stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I had an issue with my browser or ISP. Great work, however. Thank  you.

Comment: @Gert G - Yeah, that's much better than double parents call. I edited my answer.